# Space escape character in Debian Makefiles

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad, makefile, disk-usage

I'm currently trying to upload a package onto Launchpad's PPA service but I'm having problems with a path name which includes a space character. I'm trying to make a file install into a directory with a space character in it. The following is an example of the kind of directory I'm trying to install files into using the Makefile:

(/usr/share/themes/Example Directory/gtk-3.0)

I've tried the \\ escape character and have tried putting the entire path name in single quotes ('/usr/share/themes/Example Directory/gtk-3.0') in the Makefile and debian/install file in the source of the package, but it's still failing to build on Launchpad's servers.

Does anyone know any escape character that I can use in order to make Launchpad successfully build the package and make it work when I'm installing the package to my computer or are spaces in directories not supported by the Debian package system?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your build log. And try to build the package locally first via `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` to troubleshoot it instead of going through the potentially slow PPA build process (because of the queue).

Answer (score 0):

"?" can be used as a glob character, which works for spaces as well.

```
/usr/share/themes/Example?Directory/gtk-3.0
```

Note however that installing into a directory with spaces may not be the best idea, since they tend to be inconvenient (although applications should work with spaces unless they are buggy).

Answer (score 0):

You could try `/usr/share/themes/Example\040Directory/gtk-3.0` it works in fstab, you never know.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.